# iOS UIAlertView with photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I wanted to use `UIAlertView` to show photo. I´m using code as below for showing the alert, however it doesn't work. It shows the title, some space and button OK nothing more. I have no idea if I´m doing something wrong, because I´m new in iOS.

```
-(IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender
{   
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"titel"
                                                 message:nil
                                                delegate:nil //or self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 10, 85, 50)];

    [imageView setImage:@"dog.png"];
    [av setValue:imageView forKey:@"accessoryView"];

    [av show];
}
```

Comment: `UIAlertView` is meant to be used as-is and you shouldn't be messing with the view hierarchy this will get your app rejected from the Apple App review process. Please read Apple documentation regarding `UIAlertView`s. So you should **NOT** be using `setValue: forKey:@"accessoryView"` and/or `addSubview:`

Comment: It's a project for my classes so I don't need it to pass review process.

Comment: What do you mean it's a project for your classes? Is this homework? If I was your teacher and I saw someone doing this in their work I would provide them with an F, because it shows that they don't understand.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your opinion Popeye *May not be true*

Comment: What???? Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Popeye is correct what he said : `UIAlertView` is meant to be used as-is and you shouldn't be messing with the view hierarchy this will get your app rejected from the Apple App review process. Please read [Apple documentation regarding UIAlertViews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html). So you should NOT be using `setValue: forKey:@"accessoryView"` and/or `addSubview:`. Specific section below

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

### Solutions

1) Use 3 party such as [CNPPopupController](https://github.com/carsonperrotti/CNPPopupController) and many other available check [this](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=alertView&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) link

```
 OR
```

2) create of your own.

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I added the documentation to your answer as well and the specific part that states it should be used as is +1